# How to automatically get 'nice' values for first and last axis labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, axis-labels

In this plot, matplotlib automatically hides the first and last axis labels. However, the desired behavior is to always show both the first and last axis labels and that too as a 'nice' value. By 'nice' value, I mean a major tic should be present at both boundaries of the axis. For example, in the figure shown below, the x-axis would have started from -0.1 and ended at 1.5. Similarly, the y-axis would have started from -0.25 and ended at 2.00. How can this be achieved in Matplotlib?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Does this fix improve the problem? `plt.xticks(x)`

Comment: Search for `plt.MaxNLocator()` and `ax.set_xticklabels()` and make use of them.

Comment: It’s just dropping the last tick because of round off error.   Set_ylim(-0.1, 2.0001) should show the ticks.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I don't want to set the limit manually as the range is different in each call.

Comment: @swatchai I searched for both of these options, but none helped. I think the problem would be solved if we can add one additional tick on both the edges of axis. But I couldn't find a way to do this with the `AutoLocator()` or  `MaxNLocator()`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by first letting `matplotlib` find the ideal tick locations and then setting the axis limits such that one additional tick is added on both the edges of the axis.

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xdata, data)
loc, labels = plt.xticks()    #returns the current tics and lables.
min_new = loc[0] - (loc[1]-loc[0])
max_new = loc[len(loc)-1] + (loc[1]-loc[0])
plt.xlim(left=min_new, right=max_new)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(AutoLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(AutoLocator())
plt.show()
```

**Edit:**
The same could also be achieved by extending axis limits to the hidden ticks at the edges. i.e.,

```
loc, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xlim(left=loc[0], right=loc[len(loc)-1])
```